# Time duration for skip backward and skip forward for audio?

Tags: audio-interface

Are there any usability studies or objective data to determine what a good time duration would be for skipping back or skipping forward for users listening to audio on the web?  This assumes there would only be one button for skip backwards and one for skip forwards.  30 seconds?  10 seconds?  15 sections?  5 seconds?

Comment: Can't reference a study on this, but I'd recommend avoiding discrete intervals. Most audio / video players allow clicking and dragging to different points in the media in a way that makes the intervals seem continuous.

Comment: Surely it depends on the density and importance of the content: something with low density and low importance (a TV sitcom for example) could have a 30 second skip but something with high density and high importance (a bomb disposal training video for example) might need a 10sec skip. Also, are users more likely to want to skip forward by large amounts and back by small amounts? - too many variables!

Comment: I'm not aware of studies, but as @AndrewMartin says, the type of content is likely an important factor--e.g. people often use those buttons to skip ads in a podcast player, and ad reads or inserts are often a multiple number of minutes long, so a minute might be a reasonable value. While if it's a player that's mostly for radio-friendly music, chances are people aren't going to want to skip around much within the song at all, but just skip the whole song.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson - We have a draggable scrubber but the client also wants a skip back and a skip forward button where the skip is a number of seconds that feels intuitively wrong to me and wanted to see if there were any best practices.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - Great points!  Our use-case is audio content on an NPR affiliated websites, so some NPR radio shows and the audio associate with each story.

Comment: @calum_b - It will be talk "radio," not music radio.

Comment: > It will be talk radio - what about speed-up instead of skip? Also, user should be able to jump to predefined timestamps, by topic discussed for example.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth - Good ideas in general, but knowing my client they will say _"Let's just keep is simple for now."_  That's what they told me when I suggested a different duration for skipping.  And timestamps would require more workflow on their part.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Thanks for adding the extra info but none of us here is as qualified as *you* to assess how *your* content should be handled. As calum_b points out, your users may find value in skipping by segment rather than duration. Alternatively they may not want to skip at all. The only way to find out what will best suit your users and their use cases is by talking to them.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - Thanks for you advice, but as noted it's not applicable since our client has already said _"Let's keep is simple for now."_  I was looking for reasonable guidelines, not patronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a usability test on a video player once and I learned two things:

1. Make the rewind shorter ( 5 or 10 seconds). Users said things like : "Oh, I missed this part I was not paying attention" and they had to quickly rewind to see it again
2. Make the skip forward faster (15 or 20 seconds). Users either saw those parts before or were not interested and wanted to get to another section of the video quicker.